# Using SQL CTE to Replace Multiple Temporary Tables

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

I was recently introduced to SQL CTEs, and I would like to implement one here, but I am not too sure how to go about doing so with the two different tables I have in this query.  The query below does get me the results I need and only takes 2 seconds to run, however, I feel CTE is the way to go but I need assistance:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Project_Time] 

AS

create table #results
(
    ID varchar(8) null,
    lastname varchar(30) null,
    firstname varchar(30) null,
    rep_time decimal(20,2),
    project_time decimal(20,2) null,
    percent_spent decimal(5,2)
)
insert into #results
select ua.user_id, u.last_name, u.first_name, sum(session_length),
(select sum(session_length) from user_activity ua
where ua.project_id in ('5420')
and session_start_time >= '5/1/15' and session_end_time <= '8/20/15'), null
from user_activity ua
join users u
on u.user_id = ua.user_id
where ua.project_id in ('5420')
and session_start_time >= '5/1/15' and session_end_time <= '8/20/15'
group by ua.user_id, u.last_name, u.first_name

update #results 
set percent_spent = (rep_time/project_time) * 100
from #results

create table #other
(
    ID varchar(8) null,
    lastname varchar(30) null,
    firstname varchar(30) null,
    rep_time decimal(20,2) null,
    project_time decimal(20,2) null,
    percent_spent decimal(5,2)
)
insert into #other
select ua.user_id, u.last_name, u.first_name, sum(session_length), (select sum(session_length)
from user_activity ua
where ua.project_id not in ('5420')
and session_start_time >= '5/1/15' and session_end_time <= '8/20/15'), null
from user_activity ua
join users u
on u.user_id = ua.user_id
where ua.project_id not in ('5420')
and session_start_time >= '5/1/15' and session_end_time <= '8/20/15'
group by ua.user_id, u.last_name, u.first_name

update #other
set percent_spent = (rep_time/project_time) * 100.00
from #other


select r.ID, r.lastname, r.firstname, r.rep_time, r.project_time, r.percent_spent, o.rep_time, o.project_time, o.percent_spent
from #results r
full join #other o
on o.ID = r.ID
```

Comment: What exactly do you need assistance with?   What part of the CTE documentation are you having trouble understanding?

Comment: Why do you feel "CTE is the way to go"? Why are you using ambiguous, regional date formats like `m/d/yy`?

Comment: @TabAlleman I have only used CTE once before and I am not too sure whether I have to use two seperate CTEs for this query or just one, and if I only use one, how do I incorporate both temporary tables and the percentage calculations?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I feel CTE is the way to go because I am under the impression that it is much less taxing on server memory than saving a bunch of temporary tables.  Also, the date format is what I use in my rough draft of my queries, once I implement them I use a `datetime`

Comment: That is not necessarily the case - CTEs can be a lot *more* taxing on memory because they have to be materialized for every reference in the subsequent query and they aren't just thrown onto disk under memory pressure like #temp tables can. #temp tables also have the advantage of having statistics, you can implement indexes, they can simplify the work of the query optimizer, etc. If it ain't broke, don't fix it.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by removing the update (and replace the subquery by a variable):

```
declare @project_time decimal(20, 2)

select @project_time = sum(session_length) from user_activity ua
where ua.project_id in ('5420') and session_start_time >= '5/1/15' and session_end_time <= '8/20/15'

insert into #results
select ua.user_id, u.last_name, u.first_name, sum(session_length)
, @project_time
, sum(session_length) / @project_time
from user_activity ua
join users u on u.user_id = ua.user_id
where ua.project_id in ('5420') and session_start_time >= '5/1/15' and session_end_time <= '8/20/15'
group by ua.user_id, u.last_name, u.first_name
```

You can also rewrite the whole query with subqueries and no temp table:

```
select r.ID, r.lastname, r.firstname, r.rep_time, r.project_time, r.percent_spent, o.rep_time, o.project_time, o.percent_spent
from (
    select ID = ua.user_id, lastname = u.last_name, firstname = u.first_name
        , rep_time = sum(session_length)
        , project_time = @project_time, percent_spent = sum(session_length) / @project_time
    from user_activity ua
    join users u on u.user_id = ua.user_id
    where ua.project_id in ('5420') and session_start_time >= '5/1/15' and session_end_time <= '8/20/15'
    group by ua.user_id, u.last_name, u.first_name
) as r
full join (
    select ID = ua.user_id, lastname = u.last_name, firstname = u.first_name
        , rep_time = sum(session_length)
        , project_time = @project_time, percent_spent = sum(session_length) / @project_time
    from user_activity ua
    join users u on u.user_id = ua.user_id
    where ua.project_id not in ('5420') and session_start_time >= '5/1/15' and session_end_time <= '8/20/15'
    group by ua.user_id, u.last_name, u.first_name
) o
on o.ID = r.ID;
```

Or with a CTE:

```
With result as(
    select ID = ua.user_id, lastname = u.last_name, firstname = u.first_name
        , rep_time = sum(session_length)
        , project_time = @project_time, percent_spent = sum(session_length) / @project_time
    from user_activity ua
    join users u on u.user_id = ua.user_id
    where ua.project_id in ('5420') and session_start_time >= '5/1/15' and session_end_time <= '8/20/15'
    group by ua.user_id, u.last_name, u.first_name
), others as (
    select ID = ua.user_id, lastname = u.last_name, firstname = u.first_name
        , rep_time = sum(session_length)
        , project_time = @project_time, percent_spent = sum(session_length) / @project_time
    from user_activity ua
    join users u on u.user_id = ua.user_id
    where ua.project_id not in ('5420') and session_start_time >= '5/1/15' and session_end_time <= '8/20/15'
    group by ua.user_id, u.last_name, u.first_name
)
select r.ID, r.lastname, r.firstname, r.rep_time, r.project_time, r.percent_spent, o.rep_time, o.project_time, o.percent_spent
from result r
full join others o 
on o.ID = r.ID;
```

I personnaly feel that the CTE version is easier to read compared with the sub query or temp table version. Hovewer it does not mean it will be better, faster or slower.

If you want to know which one will perform better, you have to study each:

- execution plans
- IO usage
- the quantity of data involved on both side of the query and how it vary
- existing (or missing) indexes on your user activity table and its stucture
- ...

You should also declare and use the correct data type from the begining rather than perhaps fixing them later if you remember it. 
Different data type may give different execution plans.